# Make properties lazy

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

I was reading the article on best practices [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/best-practices). And i came across the following lines:

> A developer might attempt to set a property on your element before its definition has been loaded. This is especially true if the developer is using a framework which handles loading components, inserting them into to the page, and binding their properties to a model.

And the proposed solution to solve this problem was:

```
_upgradeProperty(prop) {
  if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    let value = this[prop];
    delete this[prop];
    this[prop] = value;
  }
}
```

I have been trying the understand the scenario in which this would happens, and try to understand how this fragment of code solves this problem. I have trying to find any reference material around but wasnt able to find anything similar like this.

Please could someone explain this scenario and what problem are we trying to solve here.

Comment: Your code is not initialized fully, someone sets something, you do not want to blow that value away with the default value as it is initializing.

Comment: @epascarello how is this gonna save use from that? Please could you elaborate the scenario and comment.It would be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Web Components doesn't fully initialize your element until you call `customElements.define('custom-tag', CustomElement)`; however, any `<custom-tag>` exists in the DOM as an `HTMLUnknownElement` as soon as the page renders. So in the period of time between when the page renders and when you call `customElements.define(...)`, it's possible for someone to call something like:

```
document.querySelector('custom-tag').someProperty = someValue
```

which would modify the property of the not-yet initialized `CustomElement`.

#### Why would this happen?

I think this would most likely come up as a side-effect of using Web Components with a frontend framework (Angular, Vue, etc). These frameworks often have initialization code that happens after render, and there may be situations where a user may not have sufficient control to prevent the framework from initializing before Web Components.

#### How does the code fragment solve the problem?

The fragment function, `_upgradeProperty()` is meant to be called within the `connectedCallback()`, which is called after the Web Component has been fully defined and attached to an existing element. If you have any custom setter in your class, like:

```
class CustomElement {
  set someProperty(value) {
    this._someProperty = value.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Then it's possible the property was set before the setter existed, meaning the raw value was saved directly to the instance's `someProperty` property, instead of being converted to lowercase and saved to `_someProperty`. Deleting the property and reassigning it after the setter has been defined ensures that the value is properly processed (in this case, made lowercase and saved in the right location).